# Passing value of URL link by NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

The problem is here: when i try to pass link string from one controller to another, somehow it lose part of text, and finally my NSString, which i named  self.entityLinkToWiki = Московский_Кремль, not http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Московский_Кремль as it should be!

My app have structure of table view, firstly, it load tableview, after that it pass values from XML which depends of indexPath.row. All values except web links works just fine, and i will explain the way i did this. There is part of web link in xml file:

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Московский_Кремль
To get that, i did following:

In "first" (tableView list) controller i pass values like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{


if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    NSString *string = [[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"description"];
    DetailViewController     *detailController =  segue.destinationViewController;
    detailController.descriptionStringShort  =string;
```

....a lot of code here

```
detailController.fourthPhotoString = [[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imageFourth"];

detailController.webLink = [[self.listOfPlaceDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
    objectForKey:@"webpage"];
}   
}
```

Image link has nothing to do with web link, i just post it, so you get picture that i pass values in this way and it work fine. Then, i pass values from "detail" controller to controller, that finally have UIWebView:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
```

.... a lot of code here

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"WebSegue"]){

    WebViewController *webController = segue.destinationViewController;
    webController.entityLinkToWiki = self.webLink;
    NSLog(@"WebSegue link is %@", self.webLink);


}
}
```

And NSLog says, that self.webLink is already - Московский_Кремль (incorrect value). Therefore, i didn't get correct link for my UIWebView. So now, my question is - how to get correct link passing it like i did? I don't want to bother load it from XML file in final controller, because i need information of indexPath.row, to get correct value (i have a lot of entities in XML file).

Thank you for any help you provide

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying. Are you saying that the link that's passed to the webController is just the Cyrillic string "Московский_Кремль", without the prefix "http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/"? Or are you saying that the link is not well-formed?

Comment: Yes, link is passed without prefix http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki

Comment: So log the string before you pass it. I'm guessing that you listOfPlaceDetails array only contains the last part of the link, and that you'll have to build the full URL before passing it. This is an application programming issue, not specific to segues.